# GWT- Celltable Selection issue (weird selection)

Tags: gwt, celltable

I have got a little problem with Celltables... I'm kind of newbie in GWT so need your help to figure it out =))

problem is quite simple, when I click on a row (or on a checkbox of particular row), this row becomes selected and gets blue , like on this picture :
http://s020.radikal.ru/i706/1311/f1/3de6ae1d0b9f.jpg

Then, all of a sudden  (after 2-3 sec) selected row becomes unchecked and uncoloured, but it's selected as you see on a label above, see pic :
http://s57.radikal.ru/i155/1311/6c/4dc4872886d7.jpg

All I want is that it doesn't uncheck and receive default color by itself, I want it to stay in blue. here is the code fragment I use to generate my celltable: http://pastebin.com/HHeJHXpv

Comment: You're listening selection changes and setting that selection again. Can you try to comment the tableHandler?

Comment: I've tried both, commenting  Table.getSelectionModel().setSelected(clickedObj, true);  this  and the whole handler, still the same result